# Bigquery DR complaint and Multi region support

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know about Bigquery multiregion support , could you please help me with the following queries.

1. Is multi region a solution for DR ?
2. Is there any manual intervention from the user needed if disaster occurs ? can we still access the data from secondary region ?
   3.What is the time delay to switch bigquery service from one region to another
3. Do we face any downtime and data inconsistency during this time ?

Comment: I've been trying to find details on this topic too. The best I've found is [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reliability-disaster#loss_of_region) that says multiregion does not provide availability during physical loss of a region. It does not explicitly state how multiregion behaves during regional network failure.